# Problem inserting text from newly added textbox in register.aspx page into sql server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, textbox

Hi 
The problem i'm having is that when i make a new textbox iD="LoginName" i can't refer to it in the code behind.
I was able to figure out that using RegisterUser.FindControl("LoginName") adds empty text in the database but it doesn't get the text entered when subscribing.

My code:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand =
  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
   "INSERT INTO tblGebruikers(tLogName, tGebName, tGebPassw, tGebEmail) VALUES('"
   + RegisterUser.FindControl("LoginName")+ "','" + RegisterUser.UserName
   + "','" + RegisterUser.Password + "','" + RegisterUser.Email
   + "') ", sqlConn);
```

aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="LoginName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
```

I work with VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008
Any help on what i'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that your code is highly insecure?

Comment: Hi, not really, i'm kind off new to this but this does the trick to put data in the database for the other fields, so i was wondering why it won't work for a newly added textbox. Any ideas? Do i have to configure the textbox somewhere so that RegisterUser can call this textbox?

Comment: I usually try to stay on-topic, but you should definitely read about **[SQL injection attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/30/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Guard-Against-SQL-Injection-Attacks.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

First in relation to your initial question note that FindControl returns a Control, if you want to see what someone entered into said control you will need to cast it back to a textbox and reference the Text property.

Aside from that building your SQL command in that way leaves you wide open to injection attacks.  Consider what would happen if I typed something like this into your textbox:

```
', '', '', '')GO  Drop Table tblGebruikers GO --
```

Comment: Hi, thank you i will keep in mind it isn't safe.
But i still haven't found the proper command to get the inserted text. I'm programming in C# and LoginName.Text doesn't work, neither does RegisterUser.LoginName, because it isn't recognized. This FindControl method has done something, but i don't quite understand it. I keep on searching for a solution.
<br /> Regards Mati

Comment: @mati: have you tried `((TextBox) RegisterUser.FindControl("LoginName")).Text` as Rozwel suggested? BTW, what kind of object your `RegisterUser` is exactly?

Comment: Hello, tyvm, this is probably the command i was searching for. I'm still having some problems here though, it says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I don't know yet what exactly this means, just keeping you up to date. Also the RegisterUser is a default generated tab in de register.aspx page in which these textboxes and labels are added. Not sure what you mean by that. Ty for the help Mati

Comment: <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" 
        OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" 
        CompleteSuccessText="Your account has succesfully been added.">

In case you wanted to know this :)

Comment: The exception means that FindControl is not finding a control by that name.  Most likely your wizard is defined in a way that the control is not available under this name at the time you are trying to reference it.  I am not familure with the wizard class you are using so not sure how much more help I can be.

Answer (score 1):

to close this ticket.

```
TextBox txtLogName = (TextBox)this.RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LoginName");
```

is what i was looking for.
I had to insert this in the

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

method and than I was able to write the text entered in the `LoginName` textbox to the sql server database.